# Times Table format

Tags: java

Running a simple multiplication table but it's not giving me a desired output. I want each multiplication to be on different column separated with a little space. for example let 1 multiply numbers ranging from 1 to 12 should be on single column , 2 multiply numbers ranging from 1 to 12 on another column. I don't want all to be on just one column.

```
public class multiplicationTable{

   public static void main(String[] args){

       for(int i=1; i<=12;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            for(int j=1; j<=12; j++){
               int mult=i*j;
               System.out.println(i + "*"9  + j +" = " + mult +" \t");
            }
       }   
   }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println` ends in a new line. You need to think about when you want that, and when you don't. You can use `System.out.print` to not go to a new line.

Comment: I'll just give hints since this is probably homework. Since you're always calling `System.out.println`, you're always inserting a newline after each time you print (as opposed to calling `System.out.print`, which doesn't add the newline). So change all of the `println` to `print`. That won't completely solve it though, as you'll need to insert a newline every twelve numbers. Where would be the right place for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.out.print()` method instead of `System.out.println()` method if you want to print stuff on the same line. Your program should look like this:

```
public class multiplicationTable
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   for(int i=1; i<=12;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int j=1; j<=12; j++){
             int mult=i*j;
             System.out.print(i + "*"9  + j +" = " + mult +" \t");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call System.out.println(), it moves to the next line. So if you want to print all of the numbers times x on one line, you will have do something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

     // Print the headers
     for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
         // Two tabs because the calculations take up room on the console
         System.out.print(i + "\t\t");
     }

     // Start at the next line
     System.out.println();

     // Let's define each multiplication as x * j

     // For each j...
     for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
         // ...print all of the x's and their products
         for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
             System.out.print(j + " * " + i + " = " + j * i + "\t");
         }
         // Move to the next line for the next row of j's
         System.out.println();
     }

 }
```

In this table:

1 * 1 = 1     2 * 1 = 2    3 * 1 = 3

What is changing? The first operand. Therefore, you need to nest the for loops 
as the for loop for the first operand nested in the loop for the second operand to get the desired results.

Think about it this way: for each of the second operand, print all of the calculations for the first operands in a row. This way, you get the desired columns.

If this is not what you meant, please let me know in the comments.

Hope this helps.